# Pymongo and items in DB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am writitng an article, its contents and keywords to a MongoDB database using Python..now the user can give me a keyword I need to find articles having those keywords..

I am wrting to DB as below:

```
myrecord = {"Link": link,
            "Title": title,
            "HeadLine": headline,
            "BodyText":innerBodyText,
            "Keywords":keywords,
            "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
           }
          try:
              print("Inserting the record in the DB")
              result = my_collection.insert_one(myrecord, False)
```

keywords is a list of bnary tuple

```
[("africa",3),("content",5),...]
```

I wanted to know hoe to implement above usecases..I neeed to travese all records in DB to find articles having  a particular keyword

Writing below uery for this?

```
    def getArticlesbyKeywords(self,keyword,showBody=False):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        "mongodb://mahdi:Isentia@aws-ap-southeast-1-portal.2.dblayer.com:15312,aws-ap-southeast-1-portal.0.dblayer.com:15312/BBCArticles?ssl=true",
        ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

    mydb = client['BBCArticles']
    my_collection = mydb['Articles']
    my_collection.create_index([("Keywords.key", "text")])
    print 'Articles containing  higher occurences of the keyword is sorted as follow:'
    for doc in my_collection.find({"$text": {"$search": keyword}}).sort({"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}):
        print(doc))
```

I get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api_access.py", line 21, in <module>
    api.getArticlesbyKeywords("BBC")
  File "api_access.py", line 15, in getArticlesbyKeywords
    for doc in my_collection.find({"$text": {"$search": keyword}}).sort({"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 660, in sort
    keys = helpers._index_list(key_or_list, direction)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 63, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

A sample record in my mongo DB is as follow:

```
Keywords: "[{'count': 20, 'key': 'north'}, {'count': 13, 'key': 'image'}, {'count': 13, 'key': 'korean'}, {'count': 10, 'key': 'malaysian'}, {'count': 9, 'key': 'kim'}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a slightly different schema in order to make this data queryable. Insert an array of documents instead of an array of pairs:

```
my_collection.insert_one({
    "Keywords": [{"key": "africa", "score": 3},
                 {"key": "content", "score": 5}]
})
```

Then you can query like:

```
for doc in my_collection.find({"Keywords.key": "africa"}):
    print(doc)
```

Make sure you create an index:

```
my_collection.create_index([("Keywords.key", 1)])
```

If you want more sophisticated querying, use a text index:

```
my_collection.create_index([("Keywords.key", "text")])
for doc in my_collection.find(
    {"$text": {"$search": "africa"}}
).sort({"score": {"$meta": "textScore"}}):
    print(doc)
```

See [MongoDB Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and [sort by meta](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/#sort).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, Can I make it to be sorted by higher scores when I get my result?

Comment: Yes, sort by "$meta": "textScore". I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi I get exception when I use your code, I have edited my question above.

Comment: I suspect you're using an outdated PyMongo. What is "pymongo.version"?

Answer (score 0):

use $elemMatch to search in array.

```
db.test1.find({"items":{"$elemMatch" : {"$elemMatch": {"$in": ["a"]}}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a9a9805cfd72c8efd8f315"), "name" : "a", "items" : [ [ "a", 1 ], [ "b", 2 ] ] }
```

Why not use subdocument like

keywords: [{
  kw : "africa",
  count: 3
},...]

then you can use nest . like {"keywords.kw" : "africa"} to search.